# ES6 Weak References, can I use them to see which data-objects are still referenced?

Tags: javascript, set, ecmascript-6, weak-references

I have a system where lots of data-objects are generated, and many are held onto by indices.

I currently calculate which are the "live" data-objects by asking each index which data-objects are needed to recreate it, and then producing a set from all the results (as multiple indices may refer to the same data-object).

(The set of "live" data-objects is required for fault tolerance, as the indices can be rebuilt from just those data-objects.)

On reading about ES6's weak references, I thought that weak reference were just what I needed:

If I had put all the data-objects into a `WeakSet`, then only those that were kept "alive" by being in an index, would be present.

Then I found out that you cannot iterate the objects in a weak set.

Can ES6's `WeakSet` be made to work for my use case?

If not, what are the use cases for weak references in ES6?

Comment: ES6 doesn't have weak references. It only has weak collections, which are not [*that*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30556078/1048572) [useful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29413222/1048572).

Comment: What exactly do you calculate that "live set" for? To delete the rest?

Comment: What exactly is an "index", and how does it "hold onto the data-object(s)"? Code would help.

Comment: The "live set" is sent to other servers, when they start, for fault tolerance, as pushing the live set through the indexes is sufficient to replicate their values.

Comment: An "index" is just an in-memory Javascript object which has (normal, strong) references to the data-objects which it can be queried about.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I now understand that ES6's weak collections are significantly less useful and less powerful than weak references.

Comment: @chrisdew weak references are coming - but they'll take almost another year. Of course if you're using Node there are userland weak ref implementations.