# ES6: console.log on WeakSet gives <item unknown>

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

## Why does `console.log` display WeakSet as `<items unknown>`?

```
[13:37:11] [~] node
Welcome to Node.js v14.4.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let student1 = { name: 'James', age: 26 };
undefined
> let student2 = { name: 'Julia', age: 27 };
undefined
> const roster = new WeakSet([student1, student2]);
undefined
> console.log(roster);
WeakSet { <items unknown> }
undefined
```

---

Context: I came across below example on [WeakSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) in ES6.

```
let student1 = { name: 'James', age: 26 };
let student2 = { name: 'Julia', age: 27 };
const roster = new WeakSet([student1, student2]);
console.log(roster);
```

The example suggests it should print

```
WeakSet {Object {name: 'Julia', age: 27}, Object {name: 'Richard', age: 31}}
```

But in node v14.4.0 it prints

```
WeakSet { <items unknown> }
```

Comment: Where exactly did you find that example? The page you linked on MDN notes "*There is no list of current objects stored in the collection. WeakSets are not enumerable.*"

Comment: @Bergi It's part of a [Udacity ES6 course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud356/lessons/1b997dce-e2ce-4246-b5ae-d39ca175f887/concepts/5c3fd7d7-66b4-4a9c-b61d-33dd85b8cc0e) I was looking at. It's a free course but I think the link only works if you're logged in. I was wondering the use case of WeakSet, and your [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556078/ecmascript-6-what-is-weakset-for) helped. Now I'm convinced I can't (and shouldn't) enumerate/loop through a WeakSet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node-js team decided that its hard to correctly implement that.
Here is the issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19001

So that mean that WeakSet work correctly BUT console.log will always output an empty WeakSet

If you still wanna inspect the WeakMap you can do that by using utils inspect:

```nodejs
const { inspect } = require('util');
let student1 = { name: 'James', age: 26 };
let student2 = { name: 'Julia', age: 27 };
const weakSet = new WeakSet([student1, student2]);
console.log(inspect(weakSet, { showHidden: true }));
```