# Need WeakMap (a, b) -> c

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, weakmap

I have a memoized fn, where the fn is memoized by two input references:

```
let NewRefCursor = memoized(
    (deref, swap) => refToHash(deref) + refToHash(swap), // memoizer identity fn
    (deref, swap) => new RefCursor(deref, swap)); // the function we are memoizing
```

The behavior I need is `NewRefCursor(a, b) === NewRefCursor(a, b)`. When `a` or `b` gets garbage collected, the cursor should also be garbage collected.

[`refToHash`](https://github.com/dustingetz/react-cursor/blob/e06e609c9e34104c9bf45f0f00575b13c74ccfd4/src/util.js#L81-L88) is another memoized function that uses [ES6 `WeakMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413222/what-are-the-actual-uses-of-es6-weakmap) so that references seen are still allowed to GC.

`NewRefCursor` is much trickier to memoize because it uses two parameters to determine cache hit, thus isn't compatible with `WeakMap`, thus will prevent any reference seen from ever being GC'ed. I am open to any manner of trickery, attaching private fields to input objects, probabilistic data structures. This leak needs to be solved. The only solution I have so far is to add a parameter to memoize that bounds the cache size, and tune that parameter on a per-app basis. gross.

Comment: if you create a two level weak-map (store weakmaps on weakmaps), whenever a obj on first level is gced, you lose the whole second level (when a is gced, you loose b). if b is gced, you will still have a weakmap for a, which will only be there while there is another pair (a, something). does this solve your problem or am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a two level weak-map (store weakmaps on weakmaps), whenever a obj on first level is gced, you lose the whole second level (when `a` is gced, you lose `b`). If `b` is gced, you will still have a weakmap for `a`, which will only be there while there is another pair (`a`, something). Not the best implementation, but I think it suffices:

```
function BiWeakMap() {
    this._map = new WeakMap();
}

BiWeakMap.prototype.set = function(key1, key2, value) {

    if (!this._map.has(key1)) {
        this._map.set(key1, new WeakMap());
    }

    this._map.get(key1).set(key2, value);

    return this;

};

BiWeakMap.prototype.has = function(key1, key2) {

    return this._map.has(key1) && this._map.get(key1).has(key2);

};

BiWeakMap.prototype.get = function(key1, key2) {

    return this._map.get(key1) && this._map.get(key1).get(key2);

};
```

This concept can be extended to a n-level solution. Does this solve your problem or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

See memoize in https://github.com/Dans-labs/dariah/blob/master/client/src/js/lib/utils.js
It solves the problem in a generic way by building a WeakMap index of all arguments that are objects. The WeakMap index assigns unique integers to objects, which can then be put together with the other arguments by stringify.