# True Way To Remove Property From Object (delete vs null vs undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, memory

I have a big object with a lot of `key-value` pairs (like a `dictionary`). When something happens I want to remove `key-value` from this `object`. I'm aware of [delete performance issue](https://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null) and also setting unused key to `undefined`/`null` looks like a good way but I'm still worried about `GC`. I can set `object` to `undefined` or `null` but key (`property`) still standing there and holds some `memory`. When I `delete` key, it disappears so I guess that means `GC` will `free` the key's `memory`. So it's confusing for me to find the true solution to `remove` key from a big `key-value` collection `object`. Maybe some suggestions or references?

Example:

```
var dic = {};

dic.a = 1234;
dic.b = "hello";
dic.c = "!#$";

delete dic.a;         // { b: "hello", c: "!#$" }
dic.b = undefined;    // { b: undefined, c: "!#$" }
dic.c = null;         // { b: undefined, c: null }
```

Comment: Setting the property to an `undefined` or `null` value won't remove the property it just makes the property be that specific value. So now you are mixing up property definition checks with null/undefined checks.

Comment: @MinusFour Yeah, that's why I'm worried about GC. I want property to be garbage-collected and free'd.

Comment: What performance issues are you running into deleting properties? What memory issues are you running into when leaving properties?

Comment: @Matt `delete`ing property has performance issue, making it `undefined` has memory issue. When I use `delete` I can free property's memory but it's very costly, also making it `undefined` is a fast solution but property still holds some space in memory.

Comment: @MFatihMAR That's apparent from your question but what I was trying to get at was the issue that your program is actually running into. Are you running out of memory? Are deletes taking to long? There's no generic answer to this as it's a performance/memory trade off so I think you need to provide some scope around your issues/goals. How many millions of records are your dealing with? How many are you deleting? How long lived are the objects? How large are your keys etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/prototype) instead of a fat JS object ?

```
var dic = new Map()

dic.set("a", 1234);
dic.set("b", "hello");
dic.set("c", "!#$");

dic.delete("a");
```

Depending on your use case, you may also consider using [Weak Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413222/what-are-the-actual-uses-of-es6-weakmap)

Comment: It's a workaround not a solution for "safely removing property from object". Thanks anyway :)